# I'm disappointed

Tags: discussion

For those who don't know me, I've been here for the last two and half years, give or take. I find MTV SE very friendly and a great place to share knowledge; I've always felt connected with storytelling and I consider movies and TV are the best modern way for do that for the time being. Having said that, I started storytelling, actually listening from my grandparents, then it expanded throughout my family and went on. I'm a fan of movies and TV shows alike, and I'm a fan of this community starting with the above reason. I still love this community but there are a few problems that I cannot turn a blind eye to. I think most of you know the Monica Cellio [incident](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel). It was an eye opener, but I should say it's not the whole reason I'm disappointed. If you're aware of the recent incidents mainly discussed on Main meta (including [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331513/lets-take-a-look-at-the-interaction-between-staff-and-the-power-users-of-the), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334575/dear-stack-exchange-a-statement-and-a-letter-from-your-moderators) , [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away), [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335964/changing-the-code-of-conduct-to-be-more-inclusive), and the list goes on...)

I've been somewhat constantly active as a member here. I don't know if my contributions are valued even the slightest bit, but I always tried to do what I could do to help, as best as I could.

With all that's happening - the way SO staff is treating members, problems with the new CoC, the way they implement it, having zero to very little communication, displaying unsafe, weird ads, the way SO staff behave in the face of recent events and almost everything bad that's happened - I am very much disappointed and I cannot be sure that my contributions will be the way I want them to be.

There is a very important question that almost every member should have right now,

> Is Stack Exchange Inc. still interested in cooperating with the
>   community?

Still, the answer to this seems to be *No*. I really hope this would change, but considering what they did so far, the answer went to hard *No* since.

It seems that the MTV community doesn't get affected by these problems, and I honor it. But I cannot bow down and provide my time and effort to a company which has no interest in its contributors, even they have no interest in listening to them. Again, I love the community and I'm proud to be part of it, but at the end of the day, SO Inc. decides what happens and who gets shanked without any concern about the main force who made the company what it is today.

So, as I said in the question title, I am disappointed and I cannot do this anymore under these circumstances.

I know that probably nobody'll miss me nor care that I'm not here anymore, but I urge you to give more thought, explore what really happened, how the proper authorities react and whole history of what happened and how it cause this massive disappointment throughout the communities.

I will be here, but I won't actively participate in any activities related to moderation and/or Q&A process.

I know me stepping down would be nothing and probably nobody would care. but I cannot let this just pass by and be deaf to it.

Wish you all the very best and hope to be back here if they make the environment right...

Minasan, sayōnara...

Comment: I respect your choice but I will surely miss your presence and still keep hopes for you to stay or at-least retun whenever you feel comfortable. This whole SE drama did affect me and I did address [why I am still around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334790/182734). I am equally disappointed with what's going on.

Comment: You (and others reading this) may be interested in [To stay or to quit: a conflicted user's guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336108/278659).

Comment: @AnkitSharma appreciate the thought.. I really do. I'll be around and I'll be of help if someone needs it from me. but I don't want to do anything for a company who mistreats it's core-value **this much**. I really hope they'd change, but it'll be more fruitful to hope, more possibility to happen IRL that some billionaire will ditch his/her fancy lifestyle and actually care about the people to become the Batman. I really don't know what to do about this, but as I said, I'm disappointed as hell mate..

Comment: @Randal'Thor Actually, I *did* read it before your comment and I'm still processing what should I really do. your post is helpful in many ways, and thank you for that